# Unity3D Addressables Load Scene with SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, asynchronous, addressables

I am using Unity Addressables and trying to load the scene with SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync because my loadingscreen asset is not compatible with Addressable.LoadSceneAsync.

My code is:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AddressableAssets;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.ResourceManagement.AsyncOperations;
using UnityEngine.AddressableAssets.ResourceLocators;
using UnityEngine.ResourceManagement.ResourceProviders;

public class addressable_bundles : MonoBehaviour
{    
    string SceneToLoad;
    private static AsyncOperationHandle<SceneInstance> sceneHandle;

    void Start()
    {
        Addressables.InitializeAsync().Completed += AdressablesManagerCompleted;
    }

    private void AdressablesManagerCompleted(AsyncOperationHandle<IResourceLocator> obj)
    {
        sceneHandle = Addressables.LoadSceneAsync("Assets/02_Scenes/NEW_ZONING/asset_pack_1/Episode01_v2.unity", LoadSceneMode.Additive, false);
        sceneHandle.Completed += LoadedAsset;
    }

    private void LoadedAsset(AsyncOperationHandle<SceneInstance> obj)
    {
        SceneToLoad = sceneHandle.Task.Result.Scene.path;
        SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(SceneToLoad, LoadSceneMode.Additive);
    }
}
```

My code does not even compile due to LoadedAsset method.

How can I fix this, any idea?